# Advantages of WebAssembly for AudioWorklet

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, webassembly

Cited from this article: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/audio-worklet-design-pattern

> WebAssembly is a perfect companion for AudioWorkletProcessor. The combination of these two features brings a variety of advantages to audio processing on the web, but the two biggest benefits are: a) bringing existing C/C++ audio processing code into the WebAudio ecosystem and b) **avoiding the overhead of JS JIT compilation and garbage collection in the audio processing code.**

I'm wondering what the actual advantages of using WebAssembly is here. Does WebAssembly avoid garbage collection altogether? Does this outweigh the performance hit that WebAssembly has compared to native Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does WebAssembly avoid garbage collection altogether?

Correct, WebAssembly does not have a garbage collector. WebAssembly itself is a compilation target, which is why it is currently most straightforward to compile non-garbage-collected languages to WebAssembly, for example C / C++, Rust, Go.

> Does this outweigh the performance hit that WebAssembly has compared to native Javascript?

Not sure what you mean here? WebAssembly performs faster, more predictably, and loads faster than its JavaScript equivalent. See for example how WebAssembly makes sourcemap algorithms approx x3 faster:

https://medium.com/@JevanChan/speed-up-source-map-generation-with-webassembly-google-summer-of-code-2018-e67407ed2e49

WebAssembly is especially good for algorithmic code - which is why it is great for audio processing.